# How to invoke the module of dolphindb in python

Tags: python, dolphindb

I write a module function like this:

```
module testmod
def square_sum1(x,y){
    return sum2(x-y)
}
```

Then I run it, the result is 9:

```
s = ddb.session()
s.connect(Dolphin_ip, Dolphin_port,Dolphin_user,Dolphin_password) 
s.run("use testmod;")
df=s.run("testmod::square_sum1",4,1)
print(df)
```

I write another function in testmode module:

```
def testzzz(){
    return `finish
}
```

Then I call it in python:

```
s = ddb.session()
s.connect(Dolphin_ip, Dolphin_port,Dolphin_user,Dolphin_password) 
s.run("use testmod;")
df=s.run("testmod::testzzz")
print(df)
```

But the output is just

```
testmod::testzzz
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are missing; functions without parameters still need to be parentheses.

```py
s = ddb.session() 
s.connect(Dolphin_ip,Dolphin_port,Dolphin_user,Dolphin_password) 
s.run("use testmod;")

df=s.run("testmod::testzzz()") 
print(df)
```